# Android: loader manager on load result after rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager

I am using native fragment back stack for navigation through folders and native Android LoaderManager for loading of folder data.

I am using next code for adding new fragment into the stack:

```
  getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.navigation_stack_frame, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

Lets imagine i have current stack of fragments.

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6

After rotation of device LoaderManager calls my callback and onLoadResult method in **both 6 and 5 fragment**!
The problem is - **the 5th fragment doesn't have view**. Because this fragment was replaced by the 6th and view of the 5th was destroyed.

How can figure out with this issue ?

**UPDATE**:

I am able to reproduce this issue when stack has more then 3 - 4 elements

Comment: which layout you are using to replace fragment with it ?

Comment: use getFragmentManager() instead

Comment: @sreejithvs I am using nested fragments. It is impossible to use fragment manager

Comment: @IbrahimBaz I am using FrameLayout for it

Comment: can you snap the layout contain fragments so? 
i assume fragment disappear when it can't find a place to replace with..

Comment: @IbrahimBaz I am not sure what do you want from me..